# Mac mini wont shutdown

Tags: macos, mac-mini, performance, shutdown

I can't shutdown my Late 2012 Mac mini, running El Capitan, in the normal way, by selecting the Shut Down... on the Apple menu. Every time I try, Finder vanishes and the shutdown progress freezes. I'm still able to work with the Dock, so I can shutdown using Terminal. In long term it's really annoying.

Hopefully someone has an idea whats wrong.

[EDIT] I just found out that im able to shut the system down by sign out and them use the displayed shutdown on the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Close all Mac OS X apps before shutting down
2. Try to determine if one particular app is causing the problem. Maybe one app always aborts the shutdown process. Try updating to the latest version.
3. Open Disk Utility. Choose the your main hard drive and click Repair Disk.
4. Usefully shutdown freezes are caused by incompatible or outdated drivers e.g printer, scanner software. Open OS X activity monitor. Do you see any high cpu processes or unresponsive applications that are marked red?

Comment: I had already run the Disk Utility, it didn't helped. I really can't see any applications bottlenecking my shutdown progress.

Comment: Take a look at the system log file  (Applications > Utiliies > Console). Do you see any error messages while shutting down?

Do you use a Wacom driver?
Do you use Java?

If so, try uninstall/reinstall them.

Comment: Alright I unimstalled my Wacom tablet driver, I don't use it anyway. Still no improvement.

Comment: It’s hard to debug. We don’t know which Third-Party Application you are running in the background. Thus, I can only guess which App might cause shutdown freezes. 

Do you use Little Snitch, any kind of Antivirus software or additional video-and audio driver like Cubase, Protools, Avid, Final Cut? Take a look at the system log file (Applications > Utiliies > Console). Do you see any error messages while shutting down?

Comment: I edited my post, im able to shotdown after singing out. I can't really see any errors in the console. I will have a closer look this evening.

Comment: now it's working just fine. Probably it was the Wacom driver, how did you knew? But I also started in OS X Recovery and run Reset Homefolder Permissions ans ACLs by  `resetpassword`.

Answer (score -3):

If you can acess terminal just do.

```
sudo reboot
```

or

```
sudo shutdown
```

that should reboot or shut down your system. when using sudo it will ask for a password this is the same as when you login to your profile.

Hope this helps

Comment: this might also help you 
[Click here for link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/578144/why-doesnt-running-sudo-shutdown-now-shutdown)

Comment: Timm already knows how to shutdown using Terminal, after all he did say "_I'm still able to work with the Dock, so I can shutdown using Terminal. In long term it's really annoying._"  Additionally providing a link to Ubuntu... well Ubuntu is Linux and OS X is not Linux. E.g `sudo init 0` in the accepted answer doesn't work in OS X El Capitan.  His issue is with trying to shutdown from the Apple menu and nothing in the link you provided is relevant to it.